# How to globally change language for comment text in Word 2016?

Tags: language, microsoft-word-2016

I am working collaboratively on Word documents with a colleague from Iran. He has set the document proofing language to English, but the default system language associated with the document is still Persian, so comment text, line numbers, etc. are all reading right to left. How do I reset this to English standards?

Copying and pasting the text into a new document created on my computer (which uses English as the system language) does not solve the problem. Neither does changing the language setting for comment text!